# php: validate if field starts with certain character

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, validation

I'm using the Contact Form 7 plugin on wordpress to collect data inputted in the fields, I'm now looking to set up some validation rules using this neat extension: http://code-tricks.com/contact-form-7-custom-validation-in-wordpress/ 
What I'm after is to only allow one word only in the text field (i.e. no whitespace) and this one word has to begin with the letter 'r' (not case sensitive).
I've written the no white space rule as follows:

```
//whitespace
if($name == 'WhiteSpace') {
    $WhiteSpace = $_POST['WhiteSpace'];

    if($WhiteSpace != '') {
        if (!preg_match('/\s/',$WhiteSpace)){
            $result['valid'] = true;
        } else {
            $result['valid'] = false;
            $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to incorporate the second rule into this also? So no whitespace, and the word must begin with the letter 'r'? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT:
seems `core1024` answer does work, but only one of them:

```
    //FirstField
    if($name == 'FirstField') {
        $FirstField = $_POST['FirstField'];

        if($FirstField != '') {
            if (!preg_match("/(^[^a]|\s)/i",$FirstField)){
                $result['valid'] = true;
            } else {
                $result['valid'] = false;
                $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
            }
        }
    }


//__________________________________________________________________________________________________

    //SecondField
    if($name == 'SecondField') {
        $SecondField = $_POST['SecondField'];

        if($SecondField != '') {
            if (!preg_match("/(^[^r]|\s)/i", $SecondField)) {
                $result['valid'] = true;
            } else {
                $result['valid'] = false;
                $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use this code twice, once to validate the first character being `a` on one field the second instance with the first character being `r` on another field. But it only seems the `SecondField` validation rule is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
if (!preg_match("/(^[^r]|\s)/i", $WhiteSpace)) {
```

It matches any string that doesn't start with r/R or contain space.
Here's a test:

```
$test = array(
    'sad',
    'rad',
    'ra d'
);

foreach($test as $str) {
    echo '"'.$str.'" -&gt; '.preg_match('/(^[^r]|\s)/i', $str).'<br>';
}
```

And the result:

```
"sad" -> 1
"rad" -> 0
"ra d" -> 1
```

Comment: thank's for the suggestion, doesn't seem to be working though. still allowing words that don't begin with the letter r to be submitted?

Comment: Give me an example of word that passes?

Comment: for example I've inputted 'sad' and that passed through, the nowhitespace rule still works, but it's still passing words that don't begin with the letter r

Comment: I've tested [here](http://wiki.jalakai.co.uk/include/preg.php?do=match&subject=sad&pattern=%2F%28^[^r]|\s%29%2Fi) and `sad` matches.

Comment: I want `sad` not to be accepted though because it doesn't begin with the letter `r`

Comment: So that's the point of the bang (`!`) before `preg_match`. To make it inverse. I have no idea why it's not working for you.

Comment: yes I've included the bang like so: `if($name == 'WhiteSpace') {
  $WhiteSpace = $_POST['WhiteSpace'];
  
  if($WhiteSpace != '') {
   if (!preg_match("/(^[^r]|\s)/i",$WhiteSpace)){
    $result['valid'] = true;
   } else {
    $result['valid'] = false;
    $result['reason'][$name] = 'Invalid Entry.';
   }
  }
 }` but still the field is accepting words that don't begin with the letter are, all words inputted must begin with the letter r

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
preg_match('/^r[^\s]*$/i',$WhiteSpace)
```

instead of:

```
!preg_match('/\s/',$WhiteSpace)
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work, still allowing words that don't begin with the letter r to be submitted?

Comment: @user1374796, are you sure? My regexp match string, beginned only from `r`. You also need it?

Comment: @user1374796, check changed regexp. This allow only one word, and this word beginned from `r`.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I've tried, that didn't seem to work. This now accepts both words with a space in and words that don't begin with the letter r.

Comment: @user1374796, so you kidding me? You want to check that the field value contains one word and no have whitespaces, right?

Check(match): http://regexr.com?37mp4
Not match: http://regexr.com?37mp7
Not match: http://regexr.com?37mpa

Comment: yes that's correct, the code I've put in the edit above is allowing anything to pass through and isn't validating at all.